# Add color to fieldlabel

Tags: extjs

I would like to put a red asterisk after a fieldlabel in order to say the user must fill the field. Is there a way to add directly css code in the js code? Like the parameter style for example but only for the asterisk

```
var blablaField  = new Ext.form.TextField({
fieldLabel : 'Name *',
allowBlank : false,
width : 300
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have at least three (IMO) clean ways to archive this:

To do it automatically do it for any field that didn't allow blank you should use a custom form extension like this.

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.form', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    initComponent: function() {
      var me = this;
      me.on('beforeadd', function(form, field){
        if (!field.allowBlank)
          field.labelSeparator += '<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); padding-left: 2px;">*</span>';
      });
      me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

If you just want to do it for one field you can use the **[afterLabelTextTpl](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base-cfg-afterLabelTextTpl)** or the **[afterLabelTpl](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base-cfg-afterLabelTpl)** config property and apply something like

```
<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); padding-left: 2px;">*</span>
```

Or you can add it directly to the label-text like

```
fieldLabel : 'Name<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); padding-left: 2px;">*</span>'
```

Where the first is the one I like most because you need to do nothing extra expect setting the required flag.

**Edit**

If you don't wan't to apply the asterix to any field that does not allow blank when it get's added to the form you may introduce a new property like `skipLabelAppendix`. You may set this property to any field that should not get the asterix appended after the label. And don't forget to include it into the form like so

```
me.on('beforeadd', function(form, field){
    if (!field.allowBlank && !field.skipLabelAppendix)
       field.labelSeparator += '<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); padding-left: 2px;">*</span>';
      });
```

Comment: And if you don't want this to apply to every single field with allowBlank in your form, consider turning this into a plugin that can be added on a field-by-field basis. You'd still get the flexibility of using form defaults, but not require it if you only need it for particular required fields.

Comment: @existdissolve Well IMO there are no benefits when I create a plugin for that because I have to add it to all fields. This may depend on my personal style because it is perfectly valid and I may oversee something here. Anyway I would more recommend to introduce a new property on fields that allow to skip the asterix appendix. See my edit.

Comment: Agreed. I'm not suggesting it's more beneficial than adding like you did to the form itself. Just another option. One benefit of having a plugin would be for fields that aren't necessarily in a form, such as items in a toolbar.

Comment: Instead of simply checking "if (!field.allowBlank)" , a better idea would be to use ::
  if( typeof field.allowBlank != 'undefined' && !field.allowBlank )
This would make sure that fields that do not have the allowBlank property are not selected and tagged .

Comment: @RoshanKhandelwal The default value for `allowBlank` is `true`. You are doing something wrong if you end up with `undefined`

Answer (score 4):

An approach that you might find more elegant is adding a css class to any field label that is marked with `allowBlank=false` and style your mandatory indicator in CSS.

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.form', {

    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

    listeners: {
        'beforeadd': function(){
            if (!field.allowBlank) {
                field.labelClsExtra = 'x-required';
            }
        }
    }

});
```

You can then style your field label in CSS with an `:after` pseudo utility:

```
.x-required:after {
    content: ' *';
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```