# how to mark (*) in red for mandatory field in extjs 3.4

Tags: extjs, extjs3

i have a from panel in extjs with two fields one is mandatory and another in optional so i want to give the (*)  for mandatory with extjs tooltip. here is my code :

```
    var insertJSONPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
            id: "insertJSONFP",
            baseCls: 'x-plain',
            labelWidth: 100,
            monitorValid:true,
            bodyStyle: ' padding: 15px; background-color: #ffffff' ,
            items:[new Ext.form.TextField({
                id:"collectionTextFieldId",
                fieldLabel: 'Collection Name',
                allowBlank: false,
                hidden:true,
                name: 'newCollectionName',
                anchor: '90%',
                maxLength: 50,
               }),new Ext.form.TextField({
                id:"userNameId",
                fieldLabel: 'UserName',
                allowBlank: true,
                name: 'userName',
                emptyText:'Optional',
                anchor: '90%',
                maxLength: 50,
                enableKeyEvents : true,
                })]
});
```

Comment: I believe that this was addressed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589237/add-color-to-fieldlabel

Answer (score 0):

Try to append this wherever you are giving label/text for your mandatory field

```
'<font color="red" size="3">' + '*' + '</font>'
```